# insert javascript function in html string / concat()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to concat strings in order to create html `<ul> / <li>` like that :

```
 var html = "<ul>";
 json.elements.forEach( function (tab)
 {
    html += "<li><img onclick=partager(";
    html += tab.title+","+tab.adresse+","+tab.image_url+","+tab.item_url+","+tab.url;
    html += "); src="+tab.image_url+" /><h3>"+tab.title+"</h3><p>"+tab.adresse+"</p></li>";
 });
 html += "</ul>";
```

**How can I include in the HTML the javascript function in the `<img>` tag please ? It didn't work like that ...**

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have forgotten to add quotes ("") around the HTML argument (onclick):
`<img onclick="partager(...)" ... />`
This is how your code could look (using ES6):

```
let html = '<ul>' + json.elements.map(tab => 
  `<li>
    <img onclick="partager(${[tab.title, tab.addresse, tab.image_url, tab.item_url, tab.url].join(',')})" src=${tab.image_url} />
    <h3>${tab.title}</h3>
    <p>${tab.addresse}</p>
  </li>`
).join('') + '</ul>'
```

if you don't want do use ES6, this would also work:

```
var html = '<ul>'
json.elements.forEach(function(tab) {
  html += '<li><img onclick="partager('
  html += [tab.title, tab.addresse, tab.image_url, tab.item_url, tab.url].join(',')
  html += ')" src="' + tab.image_url + ' /><h3>' + tab.title + '</h3><p>' + tab.addresse + '</p></li>'
})
html += '</ul>'
```

Comment: Almost there ! Thank you. How can I do to protect with quote those 5 values ? : `html += [tab.title, tab.adresse, tab.image_url, tab.item_url, tab.url_infos].join(',');` because I have this : `partager(Musée xxxx, 2 rue de la poule)` and I want this `partager("Musée xxxx","2 rue de la poule")`.